# Google Api For Language translation Not Work

Tags: iphone, web-services

Google Api For Language Translation Does Not Work.
i tried
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?q=hello&v=1.0&langpair=en|fr

TO Convert "hello" From English To French
But It Says:
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors", "responseStatus": 403}

1. List item

So, how can i translate data?
is there another way to translate via calling another web service.

Comment: It looks to me that the Google API for language translation is working perfectly. But it seems you are doing something they don't want you to. Why don't you contact them and ask them about the "suspected terms of service abuse"? The clue is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For me your URL gives the following response:

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", "responseStatus": 403}
```

And on the URL above:

Only paid version of translator API exist since December 2011.

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html